# Admin doesn't register address type how come (I use django)?

Tags: django-models, django-views

This is the problem:

if a address is submitted the address should automatically register a ADDRESS TYPE in the address section in my admin as you can see on this picture where an address is submitted in an checkoutform (the address type should be the shipping address): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlZcE.png)

this is the code of my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from billing.models import BillingProfile

ADDRESS_TYPES = (
    ('billing', 'Billing'),
    ('shipping', 'Shipping'),
)
# Create your models here.
class Address(models.Model):
    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile)
    address_type    = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES)
    address_line_1  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code     = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.billing_profile)
```

and this is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
# CRUD create update retrieve delete

from billing.models import BillingProfile
from .forms import AddressForm

def  checkout_address_create_view(request):
    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if billing_profile is not None:
            instance.billing_profile = billing_profile
            instance.address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping')
            instance.save()
        else:
            print("Error here")
            return redirect("cart:checkout")

        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
        else:
            return redirect("cart:checkout")
    return redirect("cart:checkout")
```

This rule should do the trick in views.py, but unfortunately not showing in the admin (as seen on the picture :(   :

```
instance.address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping')
```

Does someone has advice?

Comment: show your `admin.py` file

Comment: from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Address

admin.site.register(Address)